# RDKIT: Combine/Add particles

Tags: rdkit

I have a database of macrocycles and covalent organic cages, where I wish to add a molecule/ion into the cavity. I need to do this through RDKIT. Is there an easy method to accomplish this task?

For example:

```
from rdkit import AllChem

guest = [x_value, y_value, z_value]
cage = AllChem.MolFromMolFile('cage_file.mol')

cage_guest = cage+guest (along the lines of)
```

I am then hoping to be able to manipulate the `cage_guest` in the usual fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible natively in rdkit. You should take a look at [stk](https://github.com/lukasturcani/stk), which uses rdkit for building organic cages. [Here](https://github.com/lukasturcani/stk/blob/master/stk/molecular/topologies/cage/cage_with_guest.py) seems to be the system you require.